# CSS float issue in wordpress template

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

Having an issue on this site where the content area won't float next to my side bar.
800px content width.  If I add up my content and sidebar divs, padding, etc I'm only coming up with 773px.

This is creating a child template from and then editing the the 2011 wordpress template.

http://www.rogerscomcenter.com/

Comment: Probably nothing to do with your problem. But I'm just curious: Why are you using: `margin: 0 0 0 -26.4%;`. How can a margin ever be a negative?

Comment: That margin will pull the content further to the left.  I believe it was actually already a negative in the content.  If you notice at the top of my sidebar I actually have a few negative pixels of top-margin to pull the content up higher than the content area.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css from:

```
.left-sidebar #secondary {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 28px;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 235px;
}
```

To this:

```
.left-sidebar #secondary {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 28px;
    margin-right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 235px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this gets my content to float correctly now but the footer is overlapping the bottom of my sidebar now.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.left-sidebar #content {
    margin: 0 26px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 484px;
}

.left-sidebar #primary {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

#primary {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 -26.4% 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to get it to work unless somehow I missed something.

Comment: I might have missed something.  I fixed it in FireBug to display correctly, but may have lost track of all the changes.  It is real close though.  Do you use FireBug?

Comment: I do, that's what I was testing things in i just can't get things to work correctly.  Absolute positioning on the sidebar cuts the bottom of my sidebar off and I feel like your suggestion is close but the content still won't flow next to my sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

I've cleared all unnecessary parts, added floats and width to both elements ('primary', 'secondary' divs). All seems ok.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/804/rogerscenterforcommerce.jpg/